# Python Requests - WinError 10048 one usage of socket address

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have a script which seems to run fine one computer but not on the other. I initiate an instance of osrm-routing (local server to get drive-distances) and multithread requests:

```
def ReqOsrm(url_input):
    url_to_geocode, query_id = url_input
    try_c = 0
    while try_c < 5:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url_to_geocode)
            json_geocode = response.json()
            status = int(json_geocode['status'])
            # Found route between points
            if status == 200:
                tot_time_s = json_geocode['route_summary']['total_time']
                tot_dist_m = json_geocode['route_summary']['total_distance']
                used_from = json_geocode['via_points'][0]
                used_to = json_geocode['via_points'][1]
                out = [query_id,
                       status,
                       tot_time_s,
                       tot_dist_m,
                       used_from[0],
                       used_from[1],
                       used_to[0],
                       used_to[1]]
                return out
            # Cannot find route between points (code errors as 999)
            else:
                print("Failed: %d %s" % (query_id, url_to_geocode))
                return [query_id, 999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        except Exception as err:
            print("%s - retrying..." % err)
            time.sleep(5)
            try_c += 1
    print("Failed: %d %s" % (query_id, url_to_geocode))
    return [query_id, 999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However, on one of the computers I get this error sometimes:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /viaroute?loc=49.34343,3.30199&loc=49.56655,3.25837&alt=false&geometry=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000005E84FE9B70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted',)) - retrying...
```

If I manually enter the URL in the browser it seems to work fine so I'm not sure if it is a parallel thread issue but then it seems strange it's an issue only on one computer.

I launch the server like so using POpen:

```
def OsrmServer(self,
               osrmport=5005,
               osrmip='127.0.0.1'):
    try:
        p = Popen([self.router_loc, '-v'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        output = p.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        output = ""
    if "info" not in str(output):
        raise Exception("OSM does not seem to work properly")
    try:
        if requests.get("http://%s:%d" % (osrmip, osrmport)).status_code == 400:
            raise Exception("osrm-routed already running - force close all with task-manager")
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        pass
    Popen("%s %s -i %s -p %d" % (self.router_loc, self.map_loc, osrmip, osrmport), stdout=PIPE)
    try_c = 0
    while try_c < 30:
        try:
            if requests.get("http://%s:%d" % (osrmip, osrmport)).status_code == 400:
                return "http://%s:%d" % (osrmip, osrmport)
            else:
                raise Exception("Map could not be loaded")
        except requests.ConnectionError:
                time.sleep(10)
                try_c += 1
    raise Exception("Map could not be loaded ... taking more than 5 minutes..")
```

Comment: Your request maybe a thread but your `server answer  not a thread`. Look this : `return "http://%s:%d" % (osrmip, osrmport)` handle with main thread.

Comment: This has seemed to fix it: pool = Pool(int(cpu_count()-1)), instead of using all the threads I leave one to give some the server more capacity. I'm not sure how robust it is? Whether it would be better to have cpu_count/2

Comment: @mptevsion You should write that up as an answer and when the system allows you (in 2 days) you should accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments solved by:

```
pool = Pool(int(cpu_count()-1)
```

Instead of

```
pool = Pool() # all threads
```